# Rewriting long cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have the following  long cursor.

```
CURSOR curWeek IS SELECT DECODE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( "1", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dy'), 'mo', 'KW ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( "1", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ww'), null),
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       DECODE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("31", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dy'), 'mo', 'KW ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("31", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ww'), null)
                  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS SP, TO_CHAR(myFrom + ROWNUM - 1, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS DATUM
                          FROM MY_CAL
                         WHERE ROWNUM < TO_NUMBER( ADD_MONTHS( myFrom , 1) - 1, 'j')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(myFrom, 'j')) + 2)
                         PIVOT(MAX(DATUM) FOR SP IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31));
```

Now Im trying to rewrite it. I try to use a loop like the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE PB_HELPER (myIndex IN BINARY_INTEGER, myFrom IN DATE)  IS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sqlCommand VARCHAR2(32000);
curWeek SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
    sSqlCommand := 'SELECT ';
    FOR i IN 1..31
    LOOP
        sqlCommand := sqlCommand || 'DECODE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( "'||i||'" , ''dd.mm.yyyy''), ''dy''), ''mo'', ''KW'' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(  "'||i||'" , ''dd.mm.yyyy''), ''ww''), null),';        
    END LOOP;
   
    sqlCommand := RTRIM(sqlCommand, ',');
    sqlCommand := sqlCommand || ' FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS SP, TO_CHAR(' || myFrom || '+ ROWNUM - 1, ''dd.mm.yyyy'') AS DATUM
                                            FROM MY_CAL
                                          WHERE ROWNUM < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS('|| myFrom ||', 1) - 1, ''j'')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR('|| myFrom ||', ''j'')) + 2)
                                          PIVOT(MAX(DATUM) FOR SP IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31))';

    OPEN curWeek FOR sqlCommand USING myFrom; 
    CLOSE curWeek; 
END PB_HELPER;
```

However it doesn't work. I'm getting `ORA-00907` error. Anyone could help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would just use the long query rather than trying to "simplify" (complicate) it using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @hadjuk, can you explain what you try to achieve with this line `SELECT DECODE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( "1", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dy'), 'mo', 'KW ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( "1", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ww'), null)` . If you run this query from dual it produces an error, because `to_date("1",'dd.mm.yyyy')` is not a valid mask.

Comment: Format `WW` returns week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year. That's a rather uncommon definition, I doubt that's what you actually want. Also result of `TO_CHAR(... 'DY')` depends on current user session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` setting - it may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this; it does not simplify the query, in fact it makes it vastly more complicated. Your query appears long, but that is just a function of the number of columns, not complexity. It is a simple query. Building a function to create it dynamically is much more difficult to understand, modify (when required), more error prone, and will run slower. That all said, there is (imho) a benefit to remove a long query entirely from the base line code. (I only need to look at it if I suspect an error or it requires maintenance.) This can be bone by hiding it in a package spec.

```
 create or replace package curweek_cursor_pkg as 
    cursor curweek is 
           select decode(to_char(to_date( "1", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dy'), 'mo', 'KW ' || to_char(to_date( "1", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ww'), null),
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  decode(to_char(to_date("31", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dy'), 'mo', 'KW ' || to_char(to_date("31", 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ww'), null)
             from (select rownum as sp, to_char(myfrom + rownum - 1, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as datum
                     from my_cal
                    where rownum < to_number( add_months( myfrom , 1) - 1, 'j')) - to_number(to_char(myfrom, 'j')) + 2)
                    pivot(max(datum) for sp in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31));
end curweek_cursor_pkg;
```

Then in base code reference it as *package_name.cursor_name*. So `curweek_cursor_pkg.curweek;`  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c6d83869fa63aeafccab44d400fcb42))

Comment: Why do you think a dynamic SQL will run slower? Composing the string runs in memory and takes a few microseconds only.